# Final variable values

Tags: java, string

Let's say we have an immutable class:

```
public final class Student
{
  final String name;
  final int regNo;

  public Student(String name, int regNo)
  {
      this.name = name;
      this.regNo = regNo;
  }
  public String getName()
  {
      return name;
  }
  public int getRegNo()
  {
      return regNo;
  }
}
```

Let's say we have created final variables so that their values cannot be changed after object creation. The values for `name` and `regNo` are not yet defined here. But I do have a question. We know that if we dont assign values to them, it will take default values. So, if I dont assign any values, it will be

`name = null` & `regNo = 0`

So my question is, if its already get assigned to default values, how can we assign values to them at later point?

Comment: it will throw a compile error when it wont be assigned. also a `final` variable in a method `!=` `final` on an instance variable

Comment: Well you can *only* assign values within the constructor or at the point of declaration. It's the compiler that prevents you from assigning them elsewhere. (Probably validated at execution time.)

Comment: "*if I dont assign any values*" => how do you propose to do that?

Comment: You say that your class is immutable and at the same time want to assign fields at later point. Please define what do you want: immutable class or mutable fields.

Comment: @Lino 
Yes, we will see a compile time error. But those variables would have taken default values, but its not. In normal variables, it will display default values.
Why compiler throwing this error only for final variables?

Comment: @DmitryGorkovets
Actually I wasn't so much worried about `immutable class`, but my stress on why final variable is not taking up default values and why compiler asking us to define them unlike normal variables display default values if we dont assign to them.

Comment: with `final` you force the developer to assign a value to that variable. That's why no default is taken. Because how will it enforce the assignment when it could fallback to a default (which it doesn't)

Comment: @Lino
Thank you for the clarification!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those values will indeed be `null` and `0` before initialisation:

```
public static final class Student
{
    final String name;
    final int regNo;

    public Student(String name, int regNo) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
        System.out.println("BEFORE ASSIGNMENT:");
        System.out.println(getName());
        System.out.println(getRegNo());

        this.name = name;
        this.regNo = regNo;

        System.out.println("AFTER ASSIGNMENT:");
        System.out.println(getName());
        System.out.println(getRegNo());
    }
    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
    public int getRegNo()
    {
        return regNo;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
        new Student("Rahul", 3);
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
BEFORE ASSIGNMENT:
null
0
AFTER ASSIGNMENT:
Rahul
3
```

The compiler just won't let you use those values *directly* before initialisation. Also, it forces you to assign them once (and only once) while the object is constructed, and never re-assign them afterwards.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.1.2

Comment: Thanks for your time and brief example :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't have any default constructor (also, can't have any other constructors without assigning values to final variables - it will throw compilation error if you tried) - you won't be able to instantiate any Student object without giving name and regNo.

And whatever you give while creating new Student will be final.